# sequelize-cli db:migrate "hangs" adding a check constraint to a newly-added column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have the following migration file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
            return queryInterface.addColumn('Vendors', 'status', Sequelize.STRING(30), { transaction: t }).then(() => {
                console.log("Created column..."); // this prints
                return queryInterface.addConstraint('Vendors', ['status'], {
                    type: 'check',
                    name: 'Vendors_status_check',
                    where: {
                        status: ['UNAPPROVED', 'SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'APPROVED', 'SUSPENDED']
                    },
                }, { transaction: t });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Error::", err);
            });
        });
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
            // return queryInterface.removeColumn('Vendors', 'status', { transaction: t });
            return queryInterface.removeConstraint('Vendors', 'Vendors_status_check', { transaction: t }).then(() => {
                return queryInterface.removeColumn('Vendors', 'status', { transaction: t });
            });
        })
    }
};
```

When I run `sequelize-cli db:migrate`, I get the following output & then the the command just "hangs": never completes, never errors out:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]

Loaded configuration file "config\sequelize_config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20200224080020-vendor-status: migrating =======
Created column...
```

If I comment out `queryInterface.addConstraint` completely, the command finishes & adds the status column to the `Vendors` table. Running this migration against PostgresQL, if that makes any difference.

As per [sequelize db:migrate hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937298/]) I tried adding `dialectOptions: {ssl: true}` to sequelize config, but there was no effect other than a deprecation warning.

#### Update 1

FWIW, running the following code (i.e., without a transaction) works as expected:

```
return queryInterface.addColumn('Vendors', 'status', {type: Sequelize.STRING(30)}/* , { transaction: t } */).then(() => {
    console.log("Created column..."); // this prints
    return queryInterface.addConstraint('Vendors', ['status'], {
        type: 'check',
        name: 'Vendors_status_check',
        where: {
            status: ['UNAPPROVED', 'SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'APPROVED', 'SUSPENDED']
        },
    }/* , { transaction: t } */);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error::", err);
});
```

Comment: It's probably waiting for a lock. Check `pg_stat_activity()` from a different connection to validate that.

Comment: Hmm... this is a development DB & there's no other activity against it other than the code I am running. However, it does work without a transaction. OTOH, I've trying this with minor variations for hours before posting this question...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I figured out what `pg_stat_activity()` is (new to PostgresQL) and AFA I can make out, there are no active connections.

Comment: @markvgti did you figure this out?

Comment: @Prof can't remember , sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is old so the interfaces may have changed since then but to anyone who faces a similar 'hanging' issue with `addConstraint` in a transaction make sure you check the proper function definition: [https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~queryinterface#instance-method-addConstraint](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7Equeryinterface#instance-method-addConstraint)

At the time of writing: `async addConstraint(tableName: string, options: object): Promise`

So in the context of this question the proper format should be:

```
return queryInterface.addConstraint('Vendors', {
                    fields: ['status'],
                    type: 'check',
                    name: 'Vendors_status_check',
                    where: {
                        status: ['UNAPPROVED', 'SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'APPROVED', 'SUSPENDED']
                    },
                    transaction: t
                });
```

Note the transaction is inside the options object since the options object should be of type `QueryInterfaceOptions` which extends the `Transactionable` interface.

Answer (score -1):

addConstraint cannot take transaction as an option.  So the solution is to not wrap a call to it in a transaction.